# Create a copy/match list of variables in Excel?

Tags: excel

First, my apologies for the poorly worded question - I don't really know how to ask what I'm trying to do. =/

I have two sets of data that need to be paired and then copied into separate lists. Consider these two lists of data:

```
- ID-001
- ID-002
- ID-003
```

Then

```
- USER-001
- USER-002
- USER-003
```

The result I need will look something like this:

```
ID-001     USER-001
ID-001     USER-002
ID-001     USER-003

ID-002     USER-001
ID-002     USER-002
ID-002     USER-003

ID-003     USER-001
ID-003     USER-002
ID-003     USER-003
```

Is there a formula or technique within excel to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525315/concatenate-permutations-between-two-columns/23526267#23526267

Comment: Got it!

    =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,CEILING(ROW(1:100000)/10,1))

Simply tweak the "10" to the number of copies needed for your data set and it does the rest.

Solution found here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/876052-index-sheet2-a-a-ceiling-row-5-1-4-function-is-returning-repeats-for-some-reason.html

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,CEILING(ROW(1:100000)/COUNTA(A:A),1))` will auto-adjust to the number of items in ColA